# Dual boot Fedora 16 with OS X refit

Tags: fedora, osx, dual-boot, macintosh, refit

Having trouble with installing Fedora 16 on my Macbook Pro. While the installation itself completes without and issues, the bootloader doesn't install correctly.

I have rEFIt, which I already have installed from an earlier Ubuntu installation. So I'd really like to be able to use rEFIt to choose between OS X and Fedora.

I haven't found much written out on the issue, so my question is: Is this even possible?

Comment: I have my MBP duel booting using rEFIt and RHEL 6 so it should be possible to get Fedora going. What kind of errors are you getting? Some more information about your problem would help.

Comment: All I get at the end of the install is a message saying that the bootloader didn't install correctly and fedora won't boot.