# Dual booting on a Macbook Pro 7,1.

Tags: osx, dual-boot, macintosh, refit

I'm looking to install Linux on my Macbook Pro in a Dual Boot config. I've previously asked this question in a different fashion here: [Dual Boot Fedora 16 with OS X rEFIt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36420/dual-boot-fedora-16-with-os-x-refit).

However, it didn't really get much attention and seems to have fallen of the radar. I'd like to ask the question again, but in a different scope.

I'd like to start learning how to operate Linux and I think the best way to get this going would be having it as a boot option on my Macbook, rather than running in a VM. I've tried Ubuntu, and it was pretty but I felt like I wanted something a little bit less hand holdy.

The question I'd like to ask is such:

What distro would you recommend as a good starting point that is both simple to use (not necessarily simple like Ubuntu), compatible (or can be made compatible) with rEFIt, and compatible with dual booting on a Macbook Pro 7,1 model?

Comment: Why not have a VM for each distro you are curious about? (fedora, ubuntu, gentoo, arch, sles). You don't have to format your mac every time you switch, and drivers are much easier in vms.

Comment: This question was asked two years ago. I've given up on the idea of dual booting  my macbook. That said, I would probably go VM for any Linux environment in the future.

Comment: If you wish to try NixOS, i posted a question and an answer about it [on Superuser.SE](http://superuser.com/questions/795879/how-to-configure-dual-boot-nixos-with-mac-os-x-on-an-uefi-macbook/796642).

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully run Ubuntu 10.10, 11.10 and 12.04 on a Macbook Pro 7,1 booting under BIOS compatibility from rEFIt, as well as Ubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook Pro 8,1 with pure EFI boot from rEFIt and directly from the EFI boot manager. The [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) is a good resource for compatibility and installation information.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed F12-F16 on a Macbook that died recently.

I believe for any distro you'd need to create a partition for rEFIt.  You'd need to also install the boot loader to the linux partition instead of the MBR.  Then I think you needed to set rEFIt to MBR mode and I recall that you had to set the partition to bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this person's [post](http://news.thedigitalmachine.com/2012/04/19/quad-boot-os-x-lion-ubuntu-windows-gentoo/). It isn't quite the same, but you could ignore the pieces about Win7 & gentoo.